# Azure DB synch up - DB on VM to a separate DB on another VM

Tags: mysql, azure, database-replication

I have a Azure VM configured as DB server with a mySQL instance.
I want to replicate the DB to another Azure VM with a mysql instance. The replication has to be ongoing in near real time say every 5 mins. This is to use the second DB for a separate application. How do I go about the same?

Comment: Do you think about using Data Factory to copy/migrate the data between the two database?Create a trigger to sync the data every 5 or other minutes.

Comment: Do not need ELT/ETL just a replication - any simpler way?

Comment: I think you can create the backup file and then import them manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan to use ELT/ETL tools or services, I just have this workaround:

1. Create the MySQL instance backup file in Azure VM 1.
2. Upload the file into Azure Storage or other cloud storage.
3. Download the backup file from the Azure Storage in Azure VM 2 and
   restore it.

HTH.

Comment: I need the replication to be ongoing

Comment: @UjwalTamminedi I'm afraid to tell you that we can't achieve that for now..